# Does modifying the source code and build and resign my desktop app affect its reputation?

Tags: electron, desktop-application, code-signing-certificate, smartscreen

I have a desktop app built using Electron Framework. I have signed its installer and put it in my google drive for downloading. Because I signed with standard certificate, SmartScreen still shows warning when user runs it.

I have read some articles that says that it takes some time and downloads to build good reputation for the app. While I'm waiting for its to gain better reputation, I have some more feature to put in it. So I want to go and change its source code and rebuild and resign it with the same certificate. **Does this process of gaining reputation start over again if I do like this?**